# What is the keyboard form factor called for keyboards with arrow keys that double as home, end, page up and page down keys and has a numpad?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm looking for a keyboard with specific form factor/layout but I just don't know what it's called making it hard for me to search it on the internet.

Here's what it looks like.

[image: Keyboard]

Primary characteristics of form factor I'm looking for.

1. arrow keys that double as home, page up/down, and end keys
2. has a numpad
3. almost the same length as a TKL (Ten Key Less) keyboard

**The Question**: What form factor is this keyboard called? And how do I best search for it?

The image above is Hexgears X-1. Unfortunately, it has a deal-breaker caveat so I need to search for another similar keyboard.

Comment: Doesn’t look like an established format. So you’re out of luck, I think.

Answer (score 0):

It's a non-standard form factor. I've only discovered a few other keyboards with similar numpad placement.

One is the discontinued Cooler Master Quickfire TK, where the bottom of the numpad serves double duty as arrow keys.
[image: Quickfire TK photo]

Another is the HAVIT KB487L TKL. It's sadly missing the mathematical operation keys on the numpad, so it's better for two-factor auth entry or playing traditional roguelikes than it is for spreadsheets. It's also extremely cheap; the entire keyboard costs almost half as much a bag of Cherry MX switches alone.
[image: Havit keyboard photo]

Note that arrow key behavior can be remapped via software like Karabiner-Elements even if the hardware doesn't natively support it. Physical keyboard layout is the real sticking point.